# Data type of value returned by TRIM Function

Tags: sql

What is the data type of the value returned by trim() function in SQL?

Comment: What RDBMS is this for?'

Comment: Does the return type change for each RDBMS?

Comment: Shouldn't, but some don't have `TRIM()`

Comment: @Venk is it so difficult to modify the question to include the DB type? Help us to help you.

Comment: I was trying to TRIM CURRENT_DATE in Netezza and wanted to know what would be the return type..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, for RTRIM/LTRIM, [either varchar or nvarchar based on input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, it returns [**`VARCHAR2.`**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions207.htm#i79689) whatever you trim.